# Having Trouble Plotting JSON Data in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently pulling data that I want to plot as a simple are chart on my page. So far my code looks like this:

```
    var test = [{'minute': '09:30', 'close': 286.54}, {'minute': '09:45', 'close': 285.93}, {'minute': '10:00', 'close': 284.915}, {'minute': '10:15', 'close': 284.435}, {'minute': '10:30', 'close': 284.96}, {'minute': '10:45', 'close': 284.33}, {'minute': '11:00', 'close': 284.1}, {'minute': '11:15', 'close': 283.29}, {'minute': '11:30', 'close': 283.32}, {'minute': '11:45', 'close': 283.21}, {'minute': '12:00', 'close': 283.25}, {'minute': '12:15', 'close': 283.52}, {'minute': '12:30', 'close': 283.17}, {'minute': '12:45', 'close': 283.245}, {'minute': '13:00', 'close': 282.9}, {'minute': '13:15', 'close': 283.21}, {'minute': '13:30', 'close': 283.13}, {'minute': '13:45', 'close': 283.18}]

    Highcharts.chart('my-container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        series: [{
            data: test,
        }] /* series */
    });
```

However, this just returns a blank chart. Any idea on where I am going wrong (I'm extremely new to JS)? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am just  taking 5 items from your data and display:

```js
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container" style="width: 550px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <script language="JavaScript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var chart = {
                 type: 'bar'
             };
             var title = {
                 text: 'Example of your chart'
             };
             var subtitle = {
                 text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
             };
             var xAxis = {
                 categories: ['09:30', '09:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30'],
                 title: {
                     text: null
                 }
             };
             var yAxis = {
                 min: 0,
                 title: {
                     text: 'unit (inches)',
                     align: 'high'
                 },
                 labels: {
                     overflow: 'justify'
                 }
             };
             var tooltip = {
                 valueSuffix: ' unit'
             };
             var plotOptions = {
                 bar: {
                     dataLabels: {
                         enabled: true
                     }
                 }
             };
             var legend = {
                 layout: 'vertical',
                 align: 'right',
                 verticalAlign: 'top',
                 x: -40,
                 y: 100,
                 floating: true,
                 borderWidth: 1,
         
                 backgroundColor: (
                     (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) ||
                     '#FFFFFF'),
                 shadow: true
             };
             var credits = {
                 enabled: false
             };
             var series = [
                 {
                     name: '09:30',
                     data: [286.54]
                 },
                 {
                     name: '09:45',
                     data: [285.93]
                 },
                 {
                     name: '10:00',
                     data: [284.915]
                 },
                 {
                     name: '10:15',
                     data: [284.435]
                 },
                 {
                     name: '10:30',
                     data: [284.96]
                 },
             ];
         
             //var test = [{ 'minute': '09:30', 'close': 286.54 },
             //    { 'minute': '09:45', 'close': 285.93 },
             //    { 'minute': '10:00', 'close': 284.915 },
             //    { 'minute': '10:15', 'close': 284.435 },
             //    { 'minute': '10:30', 'close': 284.96 },
             //    { 'minute': '10:45', 'close': 284.33 },
             //    { 'minute': '11:00', 'close': 284.1 },
             //    { 'minute': '11:15', 'close': 283.29 },
             //    { 'minute': '11:30', 'close': 283.32 },
             //    { 'minute': '11:45', 'close': 283.21 },
             //    { 'minute': '12:00', 'close': 283.25 },
             //    { 'minute': '12:15', 'close': 283.52 },
             //    { 'minute': '12:30', 'close': 283.17 },
             //    { 'minute': '12:45', 'close': 283.245 },
             //    { 'minute': '13:00', 'close': 282.9 },
             //    { 'minute': '13:15', 'close': 283.21 },
             //    { 'minute': '13:30', 'close': 283.13 },
             //    { 'minute': '13:45', 'close': 283.18 }]
             var json = {};
             json.chart = chart;
             json.title = title;
             json.subtitle = subtitle;
             json.tooltip = tooltip;
             json.xAxis = xAxis;
             json.yAxis = yAxis;
             json.series = series;
             json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
             json.legend = legend;
             json.credits = credits;
             $('#container').highcharts(json);
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart is blank because your data structure is incorrect, and Highcharts don't know what do deal with it. If you need to leave the data structure as it is now, then you can quickly prepare the function which will process defined data to the desired structure, e.g like below:

```
function processData(data) {
    var arr = [];
  data.forEach(p => {
        arr.push({
        name: p.minute,
      y: p.close
    })
    })

  return arr
}
```

Then just call that function `series.data` as the value of `series.data`:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        series: [{
            data: processData(test),
        }] /* series */
    });
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/60gs2b7c/

Kind regards!